# show and hide button with multiple divs jquery mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

This is my view page:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
  <div class="row service-block" id="searchresult@(i)">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-5">
      <div class="mrb5">
        <label>abc</label>
        <label>Xyz</label>
        <input type="button" style="display:none;"class="bookappointmentbutton" id="btnAppointment" value="Book Appointment" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
}
```

And the JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#searchresult").mouseenter(function () {
    $('#btnAppointment').show();
  });
  $("#searchresult").mouseleave(function () {
    $('#btnAppointment').hide();
  });
});
```

I am displaying list of records like this:

[image]

consider this image as an example because this is how i am displaying list of records.

now i want to do is when my mouse hovers over div say for eg **searchresult0** then i want to show button and on mouseleave i want to hide button.

when my mouse hover over **searchresult1** then i want to display button and on leave hide button.

but as i am generating new div for every records i am not getting how to to this with different division.

Comment: FYI: IDs must be unique on document context

Comment: What is the outer element, in which these "searchresult" elements sit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `this` to find element in currently hovered div. also you have duplicate IDs in DOM. IDs should be unique. use class selector instead of keeping duplicate IDs:

```
    $("[id^=searchresult]").mouseenter(function () {
         $(this).find('.bookappointmentbutton').show();
    });
    $("[id^=searchresult]").mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).find('.bookappointmentbutton').hide();
    });
```

As suggested by A. Wolff, You can narrow down these two event to single event by using `.hover()`

```
$("[id^=searchresult]").hover(function () { $(this).find('.bookappointmentbutton').toggle(); });
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z1gb5jnj/)**

Comment: +1 but could be simplified as: `$("[id^=searchresult]").hover(function () {
         $(this).find('.bookappointmentbutton').toggle();
    });`

Comment: Indeed. but not sure whether delegation is required or not here as OP is looping and creating element dynamically. and hover wont be delegated.

Comment: But here you aren't delegating events anyway ;)